# Enable lock screen protector programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to enable lock screen protection programmatically in android so that no one can shut down or restart the phone except me. It simply means I want to block the dialog when the power button is pressed i.e when the power button is pressed it will not show Power Off, Restart etc by the help of the my app. Actually i want to develop an app just like the one in [smart lock screen protector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nezdroid.lockscreenprotector&hl=en) .

Comment: this is impossible unless you have a rooted phone, you can tell buttons to do other things but in general you won't have access to this

Comment: But then how this feature  works in Smart Lockscreen Protector app on non rooted phone

Comment: Certain functionality you can do it by creating guest account, but shut down and restart is not possible.